# UI-Ace autocomplete with angular

Tags: angularjs, ace-editor

I have already added ui-ace editor and everything works. Now I'm trying to add autocomplete: I added ext-language_tools.js file, but it shows an error:

> "Uncaught ReferenceError: ace is not defined. (anonymous function)
>   ext-language_tools"

My html page looks like this:

```
<div ui-ace="{ onLoad : aceLoaded, mode: 'gherkin', theme: 'chrome', require: ['ace/ext/language_tools']}" ng-model='scenario.StepsLine' join-steps-array style="height : 200px"></div>
```

and function for ace loading:

```
$scope.aceLoaded = function(_editor){
    // Editor part
    var _session = _editor.getSession();
    var _renderer = _editor.renderer;

    _editor.setOptions({
        minLines: 10,
        maxLines: 40,
        wrap: true,
        firstLineNumber: 1,
        enableBasicAutocompletion: true,
        enableSnippets: true,
        enableLiveAutocompletion: true
    })
};.
```

Also in console I have warnings about

> misspelled option "enableSnippets"
>   misspelled option "enableLiveAutocompletion"

but I guess it's a result of not-connected ext-language_tools.

Angular successfully find all of needful files:

```
<script src="/Content/app/common/ace/ext-language_tools.js"></script>
<script src="/Content/app/common/ace/ace.js"></script>
<script src="/Content/app/common/ace/mode-gherkin.js"></script>
<script src="/Content/app/common/ace/theme-chrome.js"></script>
<script src="/Content/app/common/ace/theme-twilight.js"></script>
<script src="/Content/app/common/ace/ui-ace.js"></script>
<script src="/Content/app/common/ace/snippets/gherkin.js"></script>
```

Comment: I have a thought, that the issue is that ext-language_tools somehow is added earlier that ace.js, but I don't know how to fix it, because these scripts are added automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ext-language_tools.js needs to be added after ace.js, otherwise it throws error trying to access ace global variable.
Mode and theme scripts can be skipped since ace adds them automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from including **angular-ui-ace/ui-ace.js** (UI Ace File)

have you included following files ?

- **ace-builds/src-noconflict/ace.js**
- **ace-builds/src-noconflict/ext-language_tools.js**

Comment: Yes, all of them are included and angular sees them:
<script src="/Content/app/common/ace/ace.js"></script>
<script src="/Content/app/common/ace/mode-gherkin.js"></script>
<script src="/Content/app/common/ace/theme-chrome.js"></script>
<script src="/Content/app/common/ace/theme-twilight.js"></script>
<script src="/Content/app/common/ace/ui-ace.js"></script>
<script src="/Content/app/common/ace/snippets/gherkin.js"></script>

Comment: **ext-language_tools** ?

Comment: sorry, it's somehow was higher on the page,
<script src="/Content/app/common/ace/ext-language_tools.js"></script>
presents too.